# Как создать базу данных, чтобы id увеличивался сам?

Tags: python, sqlite

Я хочу создать базу данных с таблицей в ней будут колонки id, namem, age, чтобы при каждом новом добавление в таблицу id увеличивался  сам
Вот как я ее создаю:

```
conn = sql.connect('data_per.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT,
    age INT,
    );
""")
conn.commit()
```

Потом я добавляю в нее данные:

```
lst = ['Alex', 34]
con = sql.connect('data_per.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES(?, ?);", lst)
    con.commit()
```

Выдает ошибку, что в таблице 3 столбца а пытаюсь добавить 2, почему id автоматически не добавляется, объясните что не так? я использую sqlite

Comment: Попробуйте начать с основ SQL. В частности, тут надо в запросе указать список столбцов.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, просто с базами столкнулся впервые и вот экспериментирую, последую вашему совету и начну с основ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно указывать столбцы:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)", lst)
```

При такой записе, поле `id`, будет само заполняться

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось

Comment: @Tesla, пожалуйста :)